# How to downgrade macports software to old revision?

Tags: macos, macports

I have an application that uses the software package `ffmpeg-devel` which is installed via macports.

Last month I updated macports by running `port selfupdate` and `port upgrade outdated` which installed a new version of `ffmpeg-devel`.

My Application building process then started to fail with errors mentioning compatibility.
I'm 99% sure that this happens because of the new version of `ffmpeg-devel`.

I had before `ffmpeg-devel @20130205_0`, now I have `ffmpeg-devel @20130328_0`.

I'm not a "guru" and after installing the new version I did remove the old version by mistake, so now I need to install the old `ffmpeg-devel` revision (based on date 20130328).

How can I do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Macports does not support this, but there is a workaround.

You can put the old portfile of `ffmpeg-devel` in a local portfile repository and then install ffmpeg-devel again.

1. Create a local portfile repository: [howto](http://guide.macports.org/#development.local-repositories)
2. Download the old portfile (and possibly other files) from https://svn.macports.org/repository/macports/trunk/dports/multimedia/ffmpeg-devel?p=103000 and put it in the multimedia/ffmpeg-devel directory of your local repository.
3. Run `portindex` again in your local portfile repository
4. Install ffmpeg-devel with `port install ffmpeg-devel`

Comment: Thanks for Edit, I fixed it by download manually old version and have pointed `port` to old version.