# How do you install a universal variant of an outdated version of a port file?

Tags: macos, version, macports, variant, libjpeg

OS X 10.7.5

I need the universal variant of libjpeg v8 (jpeg @8d_0+universal), but MacPorts seems to insist that if I am to have the universal variant, it must be the latest version (jpeg @9_1+universal)

I've looked through the MacPorts documentation and other resources, and I've found the description of how to install an old version, and how to install a universal build, but no explanation of why MacPorts ignores the version number I request when looking for a universal build.

Here's what I did, and what happened:

```
$ port installed jpeg
Warning: port definitions are more than two weeks old, consider using selfupdate
The following ports are currently installed:
  jpeg @8c_0
  jpeg @8d_0 (active)
  jpeg @9_1

$ sudo port install jpeg @8d_0 +universal
Password:
Warning: port definitions are more than two weeks old, consider using selfupdate
--->  Fetching archive for jpeg
--->  Attempting to fetch jpeg-9_1+universal.darwin_11.i386-x86_64.tbz2 from http://mse.uk.packages.macports.org/sites/packages.macports.org/jpeg
--->  Attempting to fetch jpeg-9_1+universal.darwin_11.i386-x86_64.tbz2 from http://packages.macports.org/jpeg
--->  Attempting to fetch jpeg-9_1+universal.darwin_11.i386-x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/jpeg
--->  Fetching distfiles for jpeg
--->  Attempting to fetch jpegsrc.v9.tar.gz from http://www.ijg.org/files/
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for jpeg
--->  Extracting jpeg
--->  Applying patches to jpeg
--->  Configuring jpeg
--->  Building jpeg
--->  Staging jpeg into destroot
--->  Installing jpeg @9_1+universal
--->  Deactivating jpeg @8d_0
--->  Cleaning jpeg
--->  Activating jpeg @9_1+universal
--->  Cleaning jpeg
--->  Updating database of binaries: 100.0%
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors: 100.0%
--->  No broken files found.

$ port installed jpeg
Warning: port definitions are more than two weeks old, consider using selfupdate
The following ports are currently installed:
  jpeg @8c_0
  jpeg @8d_0
  jpeg @9_1
  jpeg @9_1+universal (active)
```

In case it wasn't clear, the desired end state is:

```
jpeg @8c_0
jpeg @8d_0+universal (active)
jpeg @9_1
```

I tried uninstalling all the installed versions of jpeg first, then re-attempting to install jpeg @8d_0+universal, but that had no effect - MacPorts just fetched and installed jpeg @9_1+universal.  I've tried

```
sudo port install jpeg @8d_0 +universal
```

and

```
sudo port install jpeg @8d_0+universal
```

but got the same behavior.

Any suggestions for how to achieve this?  Thank you!

Comment: It occurred to me that maybe MacPorts just doesn't have a universal build of anything except jpeg @9_1.  I tried searching the [online MacPorts database of portfiles](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=library&substr=jpeg), but I'm a little unclear about how it works - I can't find jpeg v8 in that database at all, only jpeg v9, and I don't see any indication of whether a universal variant is available.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the description you used to install an old version of a port. I'm not sure the port install command accepts a @version_number argument. If you want to see old portfiles you have to go back to older revesions of the portfile repository (https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/graphics/jpeg/Portfile?rev=100000).

Comment: Huh, I guess you're right - I already had jpeg @8d_0 installed, so I guess I never really tested whether the version number did anything in the install command.  Upon further testing, the version number argument has no effect.  Could you point me to some documentation about how to use older revisions of the repo?  I see the portfile you linked to, but I have no idea how to use that info to write a MacPorts command.  Thank you!!

Comment: Have a look at my answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242834/how-to-downgrade-macports-software-to-old-revision/17188118#17188118 .